# Rollback inner transaction affects the outer transaction in hibernate spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, rollback

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Service1 {
    
    @Autowired
    Service2 service2;

    public void method1(){
        //read some records from db
         List<Record> recordList = getFromSomewhere();
            method2(recordList);

        //persist the records to db of whatever updates were made to them

    }
}


@Service
@Transactional
public class Service2 {

    @Autowired
    Service3 service3;

    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public Service2(DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

    public void method2(List<Record> recordList) {
        //process the records one by one
        


        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<>() {
                @Override
                public String doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                    try {
                        service3.process(record);
                        return "done";
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "failed";
                    }
                }
            });
    }

}


@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class Service3 {


    // Process method has to be all or none
    public void process(Record record) {
        //will throw custom/any exception
        //everything here should rollback if any exception occurs
        //this also updates the Record object
    }

}
```

In the above code, what I expect is even if the process method of Service3 throws an exception and tries to rollback, the method1 of Service1 MUST commit the records. The commit should not fail.
As of now UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown. According to me, it tries to persist, but just before it exits the method1, the below exception is seen.
`org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only`

Kindly advise any propagation strategy needs to be used or any other way.
***Note: cannot change the (rollbackFor = Exception.class) on Service3 class.***

In short: If inner transaction fails, outer transaction should be able to persist without error.

```
Language: Java 11
Framework: Spring boot (2.2.12.RELEASE) + Hibernate 
Database: Mysql 8
```

Comment: Any assistance please?

Comment: You have to run method3 in a new transaction if it can fail to avoid marking the main transaction as rollback-only. Use the transaction propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't really change `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` on `Service3` to `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` the following change on `Service2` should work:

```java
public void method2(List<Record> recordList) {
    //process the records one by one

    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public String doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                try {
                    service3.process(record);
                    return "done";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "failed";
                }
            }
        });
}
```